# python loop fails after first round?

Tags: python

Im trying to parse a distance matrix for a large number of samples:  the input file looks like this.

```
sample 1    sample 2    500
sample 1    sample 3    109
```

I have a list of samples eg:

```
sample 1
sample 2
sample 3
```

I have tried this:

```
from sys import argv
import csv
script, guuids, infile, distfile, out = argv
matrix = open(distfile, 'rb')
matrix_reader=csv.reader(matrix, delimiter='\t')
guuids_list=[]
with open(guuids, 'rb') as guuid_file:
        for line in guuid_file:
                guuids_list.append(line.strip())


with open(infile, 'rb') as guuids:

        counter=0       
        csv_reader=csv.reader(guuids, delimiter='\t')


        for line in guuids_list:
                print guuids_list[counter], guuids_list[counter + 1]
                for mline in matrix_reader:


                        if guuids_list[counter].strip() ==mline[0] and guuids_list[counter + 1].strip() == mline[1]:
                                print 'no'
                                print line.strip(), guuids_list[counter + 1], mline[2]
                        elif guuids_list[counter + 1].strip() ==mline[0] and guuids_list[counter].strip() == mline[1]:
                                print 'yes'
                                print line.strip(), guuids_list[counter + 1], mline[2]
                counter += 1

print guuids_list[1], guuids_list[2]
```

this works for the first two samples and then but nothing prints after that despite the fact that all the following sample combinations are definitely seen in the distance matrix...  any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I ran your program in python 3.4 and found that by changing the `for loop` to a `while loop` your problem is solved however you are using `python 2` which I uninstalled about a day ago so not sure if it will work for your `python` model.
Try

```
while line in guuids:
```